How is the flux through an iron core maintained constant?
The field due to primary coil sets up a field in core . And this field induces an emf in secondary coil. But the current through secondary coil produces flux , sum of flux due to primary and secondary , how is that maintained constant ?

Why did you assume that the flux is maintained constant? In a transformer the flux is clearly always changing.

At an instant, it is uniform throughout the core ?

Why should it be uniform throughout the core?

In the induced emf equations of transformers , the flux linkage of both coils is same . Which means it has to be uniform

That is an approximation. It is manifestly not the same when you include time differences. https://youtu.be/Q4XVlWqXUTU?t=151

How is it approximated ?
